# On copying, which is considered: actual or apparent size?

Tags: file-copy, size

I was wondering if I have a file that has apparent size of 1 GiB but actual size of 0 B can get copied to, for example, a USB flash stick with 512 kiB free space?

You can create a file as such using:

```
dd if=/dev/null of=big-file bs=1 seek=1GiB
```

Now you can see the apparent and actual sizes:

```
du --apparent-size -hs big-file
```

**Note**: remove the `--apparent-size` option to get the actual size.

So, the main question is: which size is taken into consideration when copying a file to some directory, be that a hard disk drive, USB flash stick, DVD, etc?

Comment: It depends on if filesystem supports fallocate or not.

Comment: That depends very much on the filesystem of the target device, and if it supports sparse files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actual size.

Of the destination file.

The [simplest implementation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Worse_is_better) is to not try to predict this in advance.

In addition to that, a small fraction is required as overhead. This overhead would be even more complex to predict.

---

Support for sparse files varies, depending on both the filesystem, and the program making the copy.  Most notably, FAT filesystems do not support sparse files.

GNU `cp` automatically detects and handles sparse files.  It does not check for space in advance.  (Based on the documentation for GNU coreutils 8.29)

> By default, sparse SOURCE files are detected by a crude  heuristic  and
>          the corresponding DEST file is made sparse as well.  That is the behavior selected by `--sparse=auto`.  Specify  `--sparse=always`  to  create  a
>          sparse  DEST  file  whenever  the  SOURCE  file  contains a long enough
>          sequence of zero bytes.

Notice that filesystems can have different block sizes.  This can cause the amount of space used by the sparse file to increase, or even decrease!

( Writing file data generally *also* requires internal filesystem structures which take up space of their own.  This is not shown in the file's size - neither the actual nor the apparent size.  In traditional UNIX filesystem design, you *also* need a free inode.  The space available for inodes is shown by `df -i`.  And most obviously, you need some space to store the file name :-) ; this is often shown in the size of the parent directory.   This is discussed specifically in the question [Can I run out of disk space by creating a very large number of empty files?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/378148/can-i-run-out-of-disk-space-by-creating-a-very-large-number-of-empty-files/) )

Comment: *"Support for sparse files varies, depending on both the filesystem, and the program making the copy."* -- This could be in bold as the first thing here... And since we're talking USB sticks, chances are it's formatted as FAT32, which I don't think will support sparse files.